# Hadoop cannot start NodeManager

Tags: hadoop, hadoop-yarn

I have installed the Hadoop Cluster which is the hadoop 0.23.9 version. I install the HDFS-1943.patch and now I can start all the namenode and datanode. (start-dfs.sh is working for me)

However, when I want to start the yarn daemons (running start-yarn.sh) , it shows the following error as the same as the previous happening:

```
[root@dbnode1 sbin]# ./start-yarn.sh
starting yarn daemons
starting resourcemanager, logging to /home/hchen/hadoop-0.23.9/logs/yarn-root-        resourcemanager-dbnode1.out

datanode: starting nodemanager, logging to /home/hchen/hadoop-0.23.9/logs/yarn-root-nodemanager-dbnode2.out

datanode: Unrecognized option: -jvm
datanode: Error: Could not create the Java Virtual Machine.
datanode: Error: A fatal exception has occurred. Program will exit.
```

I have installed the patch already and start-dfs.sh is working for me. Why start-yarn.sh does not work??

Answer (score 0):

Run HDFS as a non-root user with the appropriate permissions. Here is a [JIRA](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HDFS-1943) with more details.